# Can't Get Masonry Like Grid to Tighly Wrap Around Text if Using Boostrap Grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've been playing around with this for a while, but just can't get this to really work the way I want it to.  I've been trying to wrap the border tightly around the text and have it go into a tightly packed "masonry" style look just with CSS/Boostrap alone.  If I remove the bootstrap grid it'll do this, but if I enable it then it keeps the borders for all entries on the row as tall as the tallest one.  This impacts everyone else directly on the row and those beneath since they're aligned to the where the tallest one ends on the bottm, as opposed to each individual cell above it in all of their variability.  Can anyone shed some light on how to make this work just using CSS/Boostrap alone?  Really struggling on this one...

Here's my fiddle with what I was able to get going:
https://jsfiddle.net/rcnjstudent/ea2pt1vL/34/

HTML Code

```
  <head>
    <title>Dragula with auto width grid</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 1.</p>
            <p>This is statement 1.</p>
            <p>This is statement 1.</p>
            <p>This is statement 1.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 2.</p>
            <p>This is statement 2.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 3.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 4.</p>
            <p>This is statement 4.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 5.</p>
            <p>This is statement 5.</p>
            <p>This is statement 5.</p>
          </div>
           <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 6.</p>
          </div>
           <div class="col-3 statement">
            <p>This is statement 7.</p>
            <p>This is statement 7.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS Code

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 970px;
}

.statement {
  border: solid;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: .4em;
    padding: 1em 2.4em .6em 1em;
    /*margin: .4em;*/
    min-height: 3em;
}
```

Here's my minimal JS,was trying to use Dragula library to be able to drag and drop them into different configurations and have it snap into proper placing when shifted around.

JavaScript
`dragula($('.row').toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap, the only thing I know you can use to make Masonry-like columns is [Card Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-columns).

```html
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card statement">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is statement 1.</p>
            <p class="card-text">This is statement 1.</p>
            <p class="card-text">This is statement 1.</p>
            <p class="card-text">This is statement 1.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Optional CSS if you want to remove the default padding from the card body:

```css
.statement.card .card-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/xn1j86dk/3/

Comment: Cool thanks, this was driving me nuts but it looks like you confirmed what I suspected.  I just thought I wasn't doing something right because I'm not too proficient in CSS.